# background png's not showing mobile safari, chrome... showing fine desktop browsers

Tags: css, mobile, safari, png, sprite

I have a list and I wanted a row of icons. On hover they change position in the image sprite. This all works great in Chrome and Safari on my desktop, but looking on my actual device (iphone 6) those images are not showing. I'm not having issues with any other images either.

Any thoughts?

```
<section id="socialbar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-12 large-12 columns">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="youtube"></a></li>
                    </ul>
               </nav>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

#socialbar { background-color: #ceb55f; padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px; text-align: center;}
#socialbar ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
#socialbar ul li { display: inline-block; list-style-type: none; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;}
#socialbar li a { display: block; width: 60px; height: 60px; background-image: url(../icons/icon-facebook@2x.png); background-size: 60px 120px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0;}
#socialbar li a:hover { background-position: 0 -60px; }

#facebook { background-image: url(../icons/icon-facebook@2x.png); background-size: 60px 120px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
#twitter { background-image: url(../icons/icon-twitter@2x.png); background-size: 60px 120px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
#instagram { background-image: url(../icons/icon-instagram@2x.png); background-size: 60px 120px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
#youtube { background-image: url(../icons/icon-youtube@2x.png); background-size: 60px 120px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
```